# C# ‘dynamic’ cannot access properties from anonymous types declared in another assembly

Tags: c#, dynamic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# 4.0 dynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630370/c-4-0-dynamics)

I have a function

```
void Foo(dynamic thingy)
{

  int bar = thingy.Id;
}
```

and I call it like this

```
Foo(new {Id=42, Color="red", size = "XL"});
```

This works fine when Foo and the caller are in the same assembly. But when they are not in the same assembly Foo fails at runtime with RuntimeBinderException saying

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Id'
```

pointing at the thingy.Id line. A watch in VS shows for sure it has an Id property. Any ideas?

EDIT: this is going to be closed dup. But I thought I would just record that fact that internalsvisibleto assembly attribute worked great - tx manji

Comment: thats what I assumed it was. I guess the "internals visible to" is the way to go.  BTW if you had made this an answer then I could accept it and you get shiny points

Comment: Because it's an exact duplicate, it's better to close it and link it to the other question, to have all the answers in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Property names are case sensitive.

Could the invoker of Foo() be using `new {id=42 ...}`?