# dynamic does not contain a definition for a property from a project reference

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, dynamicobject

I am getting an error that says:

> **'object' does not contain a definition for 'Title'**

all the code is also on [github](https://github.com/eiu165/DynamicTest)

I have a ConsoleApplication1 that looks like this

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Movie m = new Movie();
            var o = new { Title = "Ghostbusters", Rating = "PG" };
            Console.WriteLine(m.PrintMovie(o));
        }
    }
}
```

and *Movie.cs*

```
public class Movie : DynamicObject
{
    public string PrintMovie(dynamic o)
    {
        return string.Format("Title={0} Rating={1}", o.Title, o.Rating);
    }
}
```

it works fine from the SAME project, but if I add ConsoleApplication2 with a reference to ConsoleApplication1 and add the Exact same code

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Movie m = new Movie();
            var o = new { Title = "Ghostbusters", Rating = "PG" };
            Console.WriteLine(m.PrintMovie(o));
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Title'**

even though it is in the dynamic object.

- o.Title 'o.Title' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'    dynamic {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException}

Here is a screen shot: [image]

I am doing something like this and trying to call the movie function from a test project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# ‘dynamic’ cannot access properties from anonymous types declared in another assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630370/c-sharp-dynamic-cannot-access-properties-from-anonymous-types-declared-in-anot)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You need to use an ExpandoObject

```
 dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
 o.Title = "Ghostbusters";
 o.Rating = "PG";

 Console.WriteLine(m.PrintMovie(o));
```

Comment: He went through a lot of trouble to write an elaborate question, it would be nice to have let him know why he's getting the error, as Robert suggests

Comment: Doesn't seem you can use the inline initializer functionality with expando object?

Comment: Where should use ExpandoObject? for creating a dynamic object or for parsing a dynamic object?

Comment: I had to search for more information since Robert's answer was helpful but I needed a deeper understanding.  Oreilly had a good article on dynamic types here: https://www.oreilly.com/learning/building-c-objects-dynamically

Answer (score 172):

Jahamal's answer doesn't say *why* you get the error. The reason is that the anonymous class is `internal` to the assembly. Keyword `dynamic` doesn't allow you to bypass member visibility.

The solution is to replace the anonymous class with named public class.

Here's another good example explaining the reason and [another possible solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20160328213802/http://www.heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2010/5/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic).

> The reason the call to `data2.Person` fails is that the type information of `data2` is not available at runtime. The reason it's not available is because anonymous types are not public. When the method is returning an instance of that anonymous type, it's returning a `System.Object` which references an instance of an anonymous type -  a type whose info isn't available to the main program. The dynamic runtime tries to find a property called `Person` on the object, but can't resolve it from the type information it has. As such, it throws an exception. The call to `data.Name` works fine since `Person` is a public class, that information is available and can be easily resolved.

> This can affect you in any of the following cases (if not more):

> 1. You're returning a non-public, non-internal type using `System.Object`.
>    2. You're returning a non-public, non-internal derived type via a public base type and accessing a property in the derived type that's not in the base type.
>    3. You're returning anything wrapped inside an anonymous type from a different assembly.

Comment: Could you cite your source in your answer, please?

Comment: @d3dave The two claims in the answer can be tested. Class visibility can be checked in .NET decompiler. Access rules for `dynamic` can be checked on a test class with members of varying visibility.

Comment: This is the real answer to why what OP was doing is a problem.

Comment: I can't get this to work between a source and test project that are both netcoreapp1.1. Any idea if it's just my fault or if this doesn't work in .NET Core?

Answer (score 37):

In my case I had a Unit Test project that I created on Visual Studio and a lot of cases where I needed to test methods on a data layer library. I didn't want to change all of them so I marked the test assembly as a friend by using:

`[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyDataLayerAssemblyName")]`

And that solved it.

Example:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo( "MyDataLayerAssembly" )]
namespace MyUnitTestProject.DataTests
{

   [TestClass]
   public class ContactTests
   {
      ...
```

References:

- [InternalsVisibleToAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx)
- [Friend Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx)

Comment: The reason is what Alexander Stepaniuk said. Your comment is the solution. Thanks!

Comment: I can't get this to work between netcoreapp1.1 projects, not sure if it's something I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: Huge Thanks Jelgab!  Now I don't have to replace dynamic with ExpanoObject!  I'm using dependency injection in my unit tests and I was unable to use dynamic and have it work from the unit test project.  But this solved it!

Comment: Note that you (the developer) has to add this in the opposite project from which the anonymous types are being created, or both, if that is the case.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I have a xUnit test project.

Where 'content' is a **json string**.

This code throws error:

```
dynamic parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
```

This code works. Use **ExpandoObject** insted of dynamic like this:

```
dynamic parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am way late to the party, but here is a way I did it.

```
dynamic myObject = GetSomeObject();

//check if myObject is a special Object
(if myObject is specialObject)
{
    string specialPropery = ((specialObject))myObject).SpecialProperty;
    Console.WriteLine("The object is a special type. SpecialPropery: {specialPropery }");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The object normal type.");
}
```