# RuntimeBinderException when reading property from `dynamic` result from method in different library

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have a static method in `MyLibrary1` which returns a dynamic object.

```
public static dynamic GetObjects()
{
return new { test = "something" };
}
```

But when I access the above method from `MyLibrary2`, debugger shows the value and object returned correctly.

```
dynamic b = MyLibrary1.GetObjects();
string name = b.test;
```

I get a `RuntimeBinderException` that says " `'object' does not contain a definition for 'test'` when I read `b.test`.

The same code works as expected when I move the method to the calling library.

Comment: Wow, this is very peculiar indeed. I've edited the title/question a little bit to make it more clear that this is a runtime exception.

Comment: I confirmed this with a console app and class library, both targeting .NET 4, and both referencing `Microsoft.CSharp.dll`.  Like the OP indicated, this works fine for me when calling the method from the console app directly. But putting the exact same code in a library causes the exception. *Paging @EricLippert !*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anonymous types are not public, and `dynamic` does not mean you can break into something internal/private and use it. Reflection does though.

You can allow other assembly to use internal types using attribute:

```
// specified in assembly, defining MyLibrary1 class
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Assembly, where you call MyLibrary1.GetObjects()")]
```

which completely fixes the issue with using anonymous type through dynamic.

Note that it means *all* internal types are accessible by specified assembly.

Comment: Checkout this answer - it suggests more standard way to move domain entities across assemblies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2630439/739558

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where to include this additional information.

I confirmed this with a console app and class library, both targeting .NET 4, and both referencing `Microsoft.CSharp.dll`. I'm comparing the results returned by the function in the same console app, to the one returned from the library.

When calling `d.GetType().GetProperties()`, both of them show the single property `test` that you've defined.

Not surprisingly then, this works for both of them:

```
    static string GetStringPropertyValue(dynamic d, string propertyName)
    {
        Type t = d.GetType();

        return t.GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(d, null);
    }
```

So I'm very befuddled as to why that works, but simply getting the `.test` property does not work for both of them.