# Unable to get values from DataItem using 'dynamic' in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using Telerik RadGrid's NeedDataSource event to bind to a anonymous type.

Now OnItemDataBound is used to bind a DropDownList inside RadGrid.

```
protected void rgQuotations_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        dynamic di = e.Item.DataItem;

        DropDownList ddlStatus = (e.Item.FindControl("ddlStatus") as DropDownList);
        if (di.Status == 4)
        {
            ddlQuoteStatus.Items.Add("4");
        }  
    }
}
```

When it tries to get value of `di.Status` it throws exception

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Status'

But I can clearly see the value by hover on it.

How can I get this value without getting error?

Comment: Can you post the content of the exception?

Comment: @user1124148 just updated the question

Comment: could di.Status be a string "4" or, say, Integer64 ?

Comment: Please see the exception.

Comment: How was the object stored in `e.Item.DataItem` created?

Comment: e.Item.DataItem will have the object(or row data) for the row which just bound to grid

Comment: Yes, but who creates the row instance? Same assembly or other? is it an anonymous type, ExpandoObject or something else?

Comment: Yes it's anonymous type. That's I'm trying to access it using dynamic but getting error. I have a class library separate that gets data from DB, creates anonymous type and returns back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# ‘dynamic’ cannot access properties from anonymous types declared in another assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630370/c-sharp-dynamic-cannot-access-properties-from-anonymous-types-declared-in-anot)

Comment: Then it's solved :) Some more info: http://www.heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2010/5/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [C# ‘dynamic’ cannot access properties from anonymous types declared in another assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630370/c-sharp-dynamic-cannot-access-properties-from-anonymous-types-declared-in-anot), you can't use an anonymous object created in another assembly because it is internal.

As you are in control of the assembly where the object is instantiated, there is one possibe workaround (not mentioned in the linked answer, so I add the answer here). You can make the originating assembly internal types visible in the assembly which uses the object, by adding `InternalsVisibleTo` assembly attribute:

```
// in assembly where you create the anonymous object
// and assuming the assembly where you use it in Grid is called Xyz
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("Xyz")]
```

Comment: At what place should I add this line exactly?

Comment: Ok..I added it above the namespace. Everything is working now! Super thanks :)

Comment: Typically, it is put in properties\assemblyinfo.cs together with other assembly level attributes like file version, copyright etc, but it is not required, you can put it anywhere.